# Hash function returning different result after deleting & replacing file

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, openssl, sha

My issue is that when I have the program running, and delete a file in said directory, when it (the same file) is placed back it returns a different value. I wondered whether this code below is the issue?

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int fd;
        int wd;
        unsigned char c[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
        int i;
        SHA512_CTX mdContext;
        int bytes;
        unsigned char data[1024];
        const int event_size = sizeof(struct inotify_event);
        const int buf_len = 1024 * (event_size + FILENAME_MAX);
        char *directory = "/home/joe/Documents/";
        char *hashDirectory = "/home/joe/Documents/_Hash/";
        char hashInBuf[500];
        char hashOutBuf[500];
        fd = inotify_init();

        if (fd < 0) {
          perror("inotify_init");
        }

        wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/home/joe/Documents", IN_CREATE);

        while (1) {
          char buff[buf_len];
          int no_of_events, count = 0;
          //SEARCH FOR NEW FILES WITHIN DIRECTORY
          no_of_events = read (fd, buff, buf_len);
          while (count < no_of_events) {
            struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *)&buff[count];
            if (event->len) {
              if ((event->mask & IN_CREATE))
              if(!(event->mask & IN_ISDIR)) {
                    snprintf(hashInBuf, sizeof(hashInBuf), "%s/%s", directory, event->name);
                    snprintf(hashOutBuf, sizeof(hashOutBuf), "%s/%s.txt", hashDirectory, event->name);
                    //OPEN FILES
                    FILE *ftest=fopen(hashInBuf, "rb");    //ORIGINAL FILE
                    FILE *ftest2=fopen(hashOutBuf, "wt");  //HASH FILE (stored in separate directory)
                    //HASH FUNCTION
                    SHA512_Init (&mdContext);
                    while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 1024, ftest)) != 0)
                        SHA512_Update (&mdContext, data, bytes);
                    SHA512_Final (c,&mdContext);
                    for(i = 0; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
                      fprintf(ftest2, "%02x", c[i]);
                      printf("%02x", c[i]);
                    }
                    fclose (ftest);
                    fclose (ftest2);
                    fflush (stdout);
                  }}
                  count += event_size + event->len;
                 }}
                 return 0;
         } //CLOSES INT MAIN
```

I can assure you the variables are defined correctly as for all intensive purposes it does work, just not correctly...

Comment: There are too many definitions hidden, difficult ( or impossible ?) to analyze / check.

A comment says _SEARCH FOR NEW FILES WITHIN DIRECTORY_ but the code **never** update/set _hashInBuf_ or _hashOutBuf_ so you always open the _same_ files, where is the magic allowing them to refer to the right files ?

From the comment _OPEN FILES_ nothing depends on the event, how can you manage something associated to the event ?

Comment: @bruno well I've added everything else - the reason for initially not including it is that it's perhaps too much for someone to go over. The problem is I can't localize the issue

Comment: your edit confirms my remark, please look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

You never set *hashInBuf* nor *hashOutBuf* so there contents is undefined and when you do

> ```
>                FILE *ftest=fopen(hashInBuf, "rb");    //ORIGINAL FILE
>                FILE *ftest2=fopen(hashOutBuf, "wt");  //HASH FILE (stored in separate directory)
> ```

you try to open files whose names was never set, and unfortunately you do not check the open failed, so

> ```
> while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 1024, ftest)) != 0)
> ```

reads nothing and because *ftest* values NULL, `SHA512_Update (&mdContext, data, bytes);` is never called etc

Several variables are never used :

- file512
- hashDirectory
- directory
- wd
- argc
- argv

Comment: I've just updated my code - I very stupidly missed out the snprintf just above where the file opens. My apologies.

Comment: @JosephSmith warning with _snprintf_ if may not put the final null character

Comment: @JosephSmith so probably you have only the choice to delete your question or to accept my answer to mark the question solved ;-)